# How can i block popups [ads] from appearing in my webview?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am creating a webview which loads some sites. I want to block popups appearing on the site, so that only legitimate Urls are seen by users. How can i achieve that ?? Browsers do detect popups and warns users about Blocking it or allowing it. So i assume that there must be a way to detect popups.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I want to block popups too , if u are able to do this please share with me :) 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

But at least for me not all popups are blocked and I can not explain why.